# Query all textbox on asp.net form and make one invisible using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to get all textbox on a asp.net form expect for `ID=TextBox1` and make everything else invisible.

Here is my code.

```
Form.Controls
    .AsQueryable()
    .OfType<TextBox>()
    .Where(x => x.ID != "TextBox1")
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(y =>
{
    y.Visible = false;
});
```

The exception I get is

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=source is not IEnumerable<>
  Source=System.Core
  StackTrace:
       at System.Linq.Queryable.AsQueryable(IEnumerable source)
       at _Default.ButtonA_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite1\Default.aspx.cs:line 17
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Why the `AsQueryable`? It doesn't server any purpose here, as far as I can tell. Also, note that `Controls` doesn't contain *all* the controls in a form, just the top level ones. Maybe you could rethink your design instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of this exception  is redundant [`AsQueryable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb353734%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It will throw `ArgumentException` **if source does not implement** `IEnumerable<T>` for some `T`. And `Controls` is `ControlCollection` and it has already implemented `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`.

Here is the source code of `AsQueryable()`:

```
public static IQueryable AsQueryable(this IEnumerable source) {
            if (source == null)
                throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
            if (source is IQueryable)
                return (IQueryable)source;
            Type enumType = TypeHelper.FindGenericType(typeof(IEnumerable<>), source.GetType());
            if (enumType == null)
                throw Error.ArgumentNotIEnumerableGeneric("source");
            return EnumerableQuery.Create(enumType.GetGenericArguments()[0], source);
        }
```

Pay attention to these lines:

```
 Type enumType = TypeHelper.FindGenericType(typeof(IEnumerable<>), source.GetType());
 if (enumType == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNotIEnumerableGeneric("source");
```

`ControlCollection` is not generic `IEnumerable`, so the exception will be thrown.

Remove `AsQueryable()` from your code. Also, `Controls` will only give you top level controls. If you want to iterate over all controls in form, then add this method:

```
  public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
        {
            yield return control;
            foreach (Control descendant in GetAllControls(control))
            {
                yield return descendant;
            }
        }
    }
```

And then:

```
   GetAllControls(Form).OfType<TextBox>()
        .Where(x => x.ID != "TextBox1")
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(y =>
    {
        y.Visible = false;
    });
```

Comment: This should take care of nested controls to ?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work to first do OfType, and then AsQueryable?

```
Form.Controls
    .OfType<TextBox>()
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where(x => x.ID != "TextBox1")
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(y =>
{
    y.Visible = false;
});
```